# jQuery dependent select options

Tags: jquery

I have a large database and i want display options in second select depending on the value of the first select using jQuery.

I want when I select for example option with value 1 for first select, display in 2nd selet options with value 1.

Can you help me with an example?

First select

```
<select id="city" name="city">
<option value="0">Select City</option>
<option value="1">Manchester</option>
<option value="2">Leicester</option>
<option value="3">Londra</option>
</select>
```

Second select

```
<select id="street" name="street">
<option value="0">Select Street</option>
<option value="1">Street 1</option>
<option value="1">Street 2</option>
<option value="1">Street 3</option>
<option value="2">Street 4</option>
<option value="2">Street 5</option>
<option value="2">Street 6</option>
.....
<option value="1200">Street 7</option>
<option value="1200">Street 8</option>
<option value="1200">Street 9</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's little improvement to [Milind Anantwar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1719752/milind-anantwar)'s answer, considering [urbz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3509874/urbz)'s comment:

- now code selects first of streets of selected city
- if there's no street for city select element resets

```js
$('#city').change(function() {
  $('#street option').hide();
  $('#street option[value="' + $(this).val() + '"]').show();
  // add this code to select 1'st of streets automaticaly 
  // when city changed
  if ($('#street option[value="' + $(this).val() + '"]').length) {
    $('#street option[value="' + $(this).val() + '"]').first().prop('selected', true);
  }
  // in case if there's no corresponding street: 
  // reset select element
  else {
    $('#street').val('');
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="city" name="city">
  <option value="0">Select City</option>
  <option value="1">Manchester</option>
  <option value="2">Leicester</option>
  <option value="3">Londra</option>
</select>

<select id="street" name="street">
  <option value="0">Select Street</option>
  <option value="1">Street 1</option>
  <option value="1">Street 2</option>
  <option value="1">Street 3</option>
  <option value="2">Street 4</option>
  <option value="2">Street 5</option>
  <option value="2">Street 6</option>
  <option value="1200">Street 7</option>
  <option value="1200">Street 8</option>
  <option value="1200">Street 9</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 4):

This should be rather straight forward:

```
$('#city').change(function(){
    $('#street option')
        .hide() // hide all
        .filter('[value="'+$(this).val()+'"]') // filter options with required value
            .show(); // and show them
});
```

Comment: It bugs out a little bit on the last one when value is empty

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('#city').change(function(){
    $('#street option').hide();
    $('#street option[value="'+$(this).val()+'"]').show()
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fuu94/87/)**

Comment: I want to display options with the same value and hide the other options

Comment: @mIH1: should be gud now.

Answer (score 1):

Here Is working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7YGb3/)**.

synchronize both dropdown with same class name.

```
<select id="city" name="city" class="city">
```

and

```
<select id="street" name="street" class="city">
```

and use some JQuery.

```
var $city = $(".city").on('change', function() {
  $city.not(this).get(0).selectedIndex = this.selectedIndex;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try this and make sure both selections have the same value

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                $('#street option').hide();
        $('#street option[value="0"]').show()
});

$('#city').change(function(){
        $('#street option').hide(); //hide all options
        $('#street option[value="'+$(this).val()+'"]').show() //show the same value options
        $('#street option[value="0"]').show() //show <option value="0">Select City</option>
        $('#street').val('0') //set option 'Select City' if user changed first select
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/vikramjakkampudi/fuu94/88/

```
$('#city').change(function(){
$('#street option[value!="'+$(this).val()+'"]').attr("disabled",true);
```

});

other option

Answer (score 0):

Here is an improvement so that the street select is active only if there is data

HTML:

```
<select id="city" name="city">
    <option value="0">Select City</option>
    <option value="1">Manchester</option>
    <option value="2">Leicester</option>
    <option value="3">Londra</option>
</select>

<select id="street" name="street">
    <option value="0">Select Street</option>
    <option value="1">Street 1</option>
    <option value="1">Street 2</option>
    <option value="1">Street 3</option>
    <option value="2">Street 4</option>
    <option value="2">Street 5</option>
    <option value="2">Street 6</option>
    <option value="1200">Street 7</option>
    <option value="1200">Street 8</option>
    <option value="1200">Street 9</option>
</select>
```

JS:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#street').prop('disabled', true);
});

$('#city').change(function() {
    $('#street option').hide();

    $('#street option[value="' + $(this).val() + '"]').show();
    // add this code to select 1'st of streets automaticaly 
    // when city changed
    if ($('#street option[value="' + $(this).val() + '"]').length) {
        $('#street option[value="' + $(this).val() + '"]').first().prop('selected', true);
        $('#street').prop('disabled', false);
    }
    // in case if there's no corresponding street: 
    // reset select element
    else {
        alert("B");
        $('#street').val('');
        $('#street').prop('disabled', true);
    };
});
```