# select2 (v4.0.0) - chained selection not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2, chained-select

I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23562694/jquery-dependent-select-options) approach using `show` and `hide` methods of jQuery, but this doesn't work for me in combination with select2 library (v4.0.0).
My example looks like this: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1Lfgk7fd/)

Is there a way (and maybe an example) to do chained selection with this plugin?

Comment: Where did you find the ul-tags in the DOM? I'm using Chrome and I can only see some span-tags after select2 was intialized :/

Comment: The link is unavailable for me.

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/30244576/359284, but I can't mark it as one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[There are multiple ways to chain Select2.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30244576/359284) Hiding `<option>` elements within a `<select>` is *not* the way that I would recommend.

Select2 does not try to detect whether or not an element is visible and instead depends on options being added and removed from the `<select>`, which is the guaranteed way to ensure that a result is not visible, no matter what plugin you use.