# Get value of selected option from dynamic dropdown using php

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have drop-down for selecting country, based on country selected state will be displayed in drop-down. From state drop-down list state has to be selected. After selection country value is displayed,, but i want to fetch n display state name also. I'm unable to get state name, Please help me how to display state name.
Php code is being used to display second dropdown list based on the value passed from first dropdown list. Its not the dropdown based on jQuery.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>jQuery Populate City Dropdown Based on Country Selected</title>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("select.country").change(function(){
        var selectedCountry = $(".country option:selected").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "post_request.php",
            data: { country : selectedCountry } 
        }).done(function(data){
            $("#response").html(data);
        });
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label>Country:</label>
                <select class="country">
                    <option>Select</option>
                    <option value="usa">United States</option>
                    <option value="india">India</option>
                    <option value="uk">United Kingdom</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td id="response">
                <!--Response will be inserted here-->
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
</body> 
</html>
```

```html
**php Code (post_request.php)**

<?php
if(isset($_POST["country"])){
    // Capture selected country
    $country = $_POST["country"];
     
    // Define country and city array
    $countryArr = array(
                    "usa" => array("New York", "Los Angeles", "California"),
                    "india" => array("Mumbai", "New Delhi", "Bangalore"),
                    "uk" => array("London", "Manchester", "Liverpool")
                );
     
    // Display city dropdown based on country name
    if($country !== 'Select'){
        echo "<label>City:</label>";
        echo "<select id='state' class='state'>";
        foreach($countryArr[$country] as $value12){
            echo "<option value='$value12'>". $value12 . "</option>"; 
   
        }
        echo "</select>"; 
    } 
}
echo $country; 
//echo $state;

?>
```

[image: country is displaying, but not state]

Comment: This code works fine in my case, except you need a die statement after `if($country !== 'Select')` ending brace. Also remove `echo $country;` after `if(isset($_POST["country"]))` ending brace.

Comment: echo $country, from this line im able to display country name.. same wise i want to display state name

Comment: As in above screenshot, India is displaying,, likewise Mumbai should also be displayed if selected Mumbai

Comment: If you update the existing elements, the event on them will delegate and you will need to set the event again. The better option is to use json for these types of task which won't require event delegation. However, if you are still interested in doing this using html, you should search for event delegation in jQuery.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery dependent select options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23562694/jquery-dependent-select-options)

Comment: thank u for useful link

Comment: What would the `state name` be for the UK - London etc? Do you mean the capital city?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I understood correctly that after selecting a city from the second dropdown you also wish that value to appear after the country name? You could perhaps try like this - though no doubt jQuery has a better method of assigning the event handler to the second dropdown than this(?)

The php is in the same file here for testing only.

By adding `selected disabled` to both dropdowns means the initial value of `select` or `please select` cannot be chosen once a selection has been made- just a little enhancement perhaps ;-)

```
<?php

    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && !empty( $_POST["country"] ) ){

        $cities = array(
                        'usa'   => array('New York', 'Los Angeles', 'California'),
                        'india' => array('Mumbai', 'New Delhi', 'Bangalore'),
                        'uk'    => array('London', 'Manchester', 'Liverpool')
                    );      

        if( isset( $_POST['country'] ) && array_key_exists( $_POST['country'], $cities ) ){

            $arr=$cities[ $_POST['country'] ];

            echo "
            <label>City:</label>
                <select id='state' class='state' onchange='dispcity(this.value)'>
                    <option selected disabled>Please Select";

            foreach( $arr as $key => $value ){
                printf("<option value='%s'>%s",$value,$value);
            }
            echo "
            </select>

            <span id='info'>
            {$_POST['country']}
            </span>"; 

        }
        exit(); 
    }

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>jQuery Populate City Dropdown Based on Country Selected</title>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("select.country").change(function(){
            var selectedCountry = $(".country option:selected").val();
            if( selectedCountry=='Select' ){
                $("#response").html('');
                return;
            }
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: location.href, //"post_request.php",
                data: { country : selectedCountry } 
            }).done(function(data){
                $("#response").html(data);
            });
        });
    });
    function dispcity( value ){
        $("#info").html( $("select.country").val() +', '+ value )
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label>Country:</label>
                <select class="country">
                    <option selected disabled>Select Country</option>
                    <option value="usa">United States</option>
                    <option value="india">India</option>
                    <option value="uk">United Kingdom</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td id="response">
                <!--Response will be inserted here-->
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
</body> 
</html>
```